# Stripping metadata from MP3 files

Tags: audio, mp3, music, metadata

Is there a way I can bulk strip mp3 meta data from files? Preferably from the command line on OS X or Linux?

I recently tried to use TuneUp (an app that is supposed to located mis-named tracks and fix them) but it has completely ruined my music collection and I just want to start over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mid3v2
```

On newer versions of Linux you'll probably need to use the following instead:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mutagen
```

As its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mid3v2) states, `-D` or `--delete-all` will delete all ID3 tags.

Comment: Is there an OS X version of this or a way to use it on OS X? No sweat if it's not, would just rather do it on my main machine.

Comment: Absolutely, the Mutagen module for Python [will work on OS X](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10871) as well.

Comment: One last thing - is there an easy way to use Mutagen to recursively go through a direcory and erase all ID3 files?

Comment: mid3v2 should allow you to use wildcards such as *.mp3, but I'm not sure what the exact syntax is for `find` on OS X. It shouldn't be too hard though to figure out how to use `find` to locate all MP3s and execute a command for them all. If in doubt you can always post a new question.